# requestFileSystem not calling any callback in iOS 7.1 and working in Android

Tags: cordova, filesystems, cordova-3

I have tested my app in Android devices and it is working as expected but in IOS 7.1 isn´t. It is quite strange because requestFileSystem is not firing any callback.

I am generating the app with online phonegap build (phonegap version 3.4.0).

I can see RequestFileSystem exists in window object.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, error);
```

Comment: Can you post your config.xml? There might be a missing plugin/feature.

Comment: I have added these plugins:

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.0.1" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.2"/>'

Thanks!

Comment: Are you testing in IOS device?

Comment: Yes, I tested it in IOS device aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the `<feature>` tags in your config.xml as detailed in the [File plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) documentation.

Your config.xml should look something like this:

```
<widget ...>
   <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
   <feature name="File">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
   </feature>
   ...
</widget>
```

Also make sure you call window.requestFileSystem *after* the deviceready event.